# Apply with user defined functions

Tags: r, apply

I have a user defined function that I am trying to use with apply on a matrix. Maybe the example will explain it better:

```
modFn<-function(x)
{
   mod10 = x %% 10;

   return(mod10)
}

mat = matrix(100:119, nrow = 5, ncol = 4)

apply(mat, 1, modFn)
```

It doesn't give me the output that I need. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this give the output that you need: `mat %% 10`? If not, what do you need?

Answer (score 3):

The 1 in

```
apply(mat, 1, modFn)
```

Indicates you are working by rows... and then the apply function returns a matrix which cols relate to your original rows... ie. transposed.

Probably what you are thinking about is:

```
apply(mat, 2, modFn)
```

But this is the same as `mat %% 10` as Stibu mentioned.

```
(mat %% 10) == t (apply(mat, 1, modFn))
```